# Delete and modify fields shown in "drupalsite/node/XXX"

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-nodes

I need to delete/modify some fields shown in the full view of a node. This is when you go to "drupalsite/node/XXX".

(They only will be shown depending of the value of another field of the same node).

I have used nodeapi > view but I am not able to make it work. What am I missing? How should I do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function `template_preprocess_node(&$variables) in {your_theme}/template.php`